# Remap key to modifier+key

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard, windows-registry, remapping, key-binding

I want to remap the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

I've been following to these [Scan codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa299374%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), created Scancode Map in the registry and its contents are:

```
0000 0000
0200 0000
5D00 1DE0
0000
```

where 5D00 is F10 with a left Shift modifier,
1DE0 is control right(I've remapped this to a letter and it works).

PS: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> brings up the context menu, the menu that pops up when you right click.

Comment: autohotkey will certainly be easier, but +1 if you do manage to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/rbinter/it/06/0.html), `E0` acts an escape scan code, and when combined with `F10` signals key `F15`. `F15` in Windows pops up the context menu.

Newer keyboards lack keys F13-F24, but in my case I was able to map the Right Control Key to the Windows context menu with the following register entry at

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Control/Keyboard Layout

and created entry (case sensitive)

> "Scancode Map" of type REG_BINARY.

and inside

```
0000 0000
0200 0000
5DE0 1DE0
0000
```